# File.Copy and after-copy error checking

Tags: c#, .net, smb

I would like to ask if anyone knows about reliability of File.Copy in a UNC path file copy. I have a file locally and the target is an smb share (SAMBA etc). Take for granted that the impersonation has took place successfully and I can execute commands with full credentials. Is there any way to check whether the file is properly copied?

-The solution of an integrity test will require to transfer data back, as the CIFS underlying protocol doesn't have the relevant control mechanisms (md5, etc).

-The only thing I have found is that the protocol has actually a write validation flag (check [cifs](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-leach-cifs-v1-spec-01) spec at page 80) but how can this be setted through .NET? There isn't an after-copy validation test as far as I understand through the [documented exceptions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c6cfw35a.aspx).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would hash the file before and after the copy and then make sure that the hashes are identical.

Comment: Hashing the file on the UNC path after the copy, would mean that the file would be copied back. This is not reliable because an error could occur on either of the transfers.

Comment: You would not have to do a second explicit file transfer. You could just load the file from the remote UNC. In any case an error could occur in the initial transfer of in the file open. So in addition to comparing the hash, you would want to consider an IOException as another criteria of failure.

Comment: The transfer isn't going to be done explicitly but implicitly (that's for sure). Think about it, you hash a remote file. You DON'T have access to system functions there, the CIFS protocol only does, read / write operations. By calling an integrity checker function with the UNC file as input, isn't the file going to be read across the network? The remote file isn't going to be hashed in the remote system, but in the local execution environment!

Comment: You are correct. The copy is implicit. You always risk an IOException. While it is not completely reliable, if it does succeed and the hash matches, you have your guarantee that the original copy is reliable.

Comment: Unless you let the target machine calculate the file hash, this is not correct. Like Aggelos Biboudis already mentioned, you will copy the file twice (one time for the copy, one time to calculate the checksum). File integrity is an operating system responsibility and since samba uses TCP, the network stream is also reliable. If anything happens, you should get an IOException.